# Optimize away debug tracing

Tags: javascript, typescript

In trying to debug a very rare bug in tests I'm writing, I decided to add a very homebrew tracing mechanism to my code.  Basically I have

```js
#tracer?: Array<string>;
myclass.setTracer(tracer?: Array<string>) {
   this.#tracer = tracer;
}

#trace(msg: string) {
if (this.#tracer) {
   this.#tracer.push(msg);
}
```

I can then add a call to `setTracer(someArrayOfString)` and pepper my code with

```js
this.#trace("my message");
```

and if I fail, print out the trace I have in someArrayOfStrings to try and figure out what went wrong.

However, this would seemingly have a performance hit, especially if I'm creating unique strings (i.e. interpolating variables).

I figure, I could probably do something like to avoid the string creation (though maybe I'm wrong about the optimizations)

```js
(this.#tracer !== undefined) && this.#tracer.push(msg);
```

but I find peppering my code with that instead of the the "cleaner" this.#trace() call (that effectively does the same logical thing, but only after string has been created).

Is it possible to improve this?  I assume others have thought of this, and perhaps have better solutions that I'd be willing to implement (just don't know them).

any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the **empty function** instead of any check for `#trace` or `#tracer`.

For example:

```js
#trace = () => {}; /* always keep that is empy function */
setTracer (/*String[]*/ tracer) {
     if (tracer) {
         this.#trace = (msg) => tracer.push(msg);
     } else {
         this.#trace = () => {};
     }
}
```

Below is my test code, assuming a production environment where you don't use `setTracer`:

```js
const LoopEffort = 100 * 1000 * 1000;

class TestRunner1 {
    #trace = () => {}; /* always keep that is empy function */
    
    setTracer (/*String[]*/ tracer) {
        if (tracer) {
            this.#trace = (msg) => tracer.push(msg);
        } else {
            this.#trace = () => {};
        }
    }

    run (timeLabel) {
        console.time(timeLabel);
        for(let i = 0; i < LoopEffort; i++) {
            this.#trace("OK");
        }
        console.timeEnd(timeLabel);
    }
}

class TestRunner2 {
    #trace = undefined;
    
    setTracer (/*String[]*/ tracer) {
        if (tracer) {
            this.#trace = (msg) => tracer.push(msg);
        } else {
            this.#trace = undefined;
        }
    }

    run (timeLabel) {
        console.time(timeLabel);
        for(let i = 0; i < LoopEffort; i++) {
            this.#trace?.("OK");
        }
        console.timeEnd(timeLabel);
    }
}

class TestRunner3 {
    #tracer = undefined;
    
    #trace (msg) {
        if (this.#tracer) {
            this.#tracer.push(msg);
        }
    }
    
    setTracer (/*String[]*/ tracer) {
        this.#tracer = tracer;
    }

    run (timeLabel) {
        console.time(timeLabel);
        for(let i = 0; i < LoopEffort; i++) {
            this.#trace("OK");
        }
        console.timeEnd(timeLabel);
    }
}

class TestRunner4 {
    #tracer = undefined;
    
    #trace (msg) {
         this.#tracer?.push(msg);
    }
    
    setTracer (/*String[]*/ tracer) {
        this.#tracer = tracer;
    }

    run (timeLabel) {
        console.time(timeLabel);
        for(let i = 0; i < LoopEffort; i++) {
            this.#trace("OK");
        }
        console.timeEnd(timeLabel);
    }
}

/* execute */
new TestRunner1().run("Using empty function");
new TestRunner2().run("Using optional chaining on #trace");
new TestRunner3().run("Check null of #tracer");
new TestRunner4().run("Using optional chaining on #tracer");
```

Using an **empty function** completely beats the other contenders!

Comment: interesting.  numbers are always good.  One thing that I'd need to see is that your example is using a static string, there's no string interpolation going on.  So the string is stored only once. If string interpolation was going on, I'd wonder i the results would be different.

Comment: ran it with string interpolation and it didn't make much of a difference, so this is the solution I'm going with.  thanks.

though if one has a non bespoke way to do it, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**: Rather than doing something bespoke, you might consider looking into existing tools for doing tracing/instrumention. But taking the question as asked:

You can avoid the string interpolation by making the `#trace` method, itself, the thing that's either `undefined` or a function:

```
class Example {
    #tracer?: Array<string>;
    #trace?: (msg: string) => void;

    setTracer(tracer?: Array<string>) {
        this.#tracer = tracer;
        if (tracer) {
            this.#trace = (msg) => {
                tracer.push(msg);
            };
        } else {
            this.#trace = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) on the actual calls:

```
this.#trace?.(`a = ${a}, b = ${b}`);
//         ^^
```

If that statement executes when `this.#trace` is `undefined`, the string interpolation is never performed, because the statement short-circuits as of the optional chaining (`.?`). That's specified behavior.

In JavaScript you'd have the concern that you could easily forget the `.?`, but not in TypeScript; TypeScript will show you an error if you forget it, thanks to `#trace` potentially being `undefined`.

If you want to prove that the interpolation doesn't happen to yourself, you can do one with a side-effect:

```
const sideEffect = () => {
    console.log("interpolated!");
    return 42;
};
this.#trace?.(`${sideEffect()}`);
```

Example in JavaScript:

```js
class Example {
    #tracer;
    #trace;

    setTracer(tracer) {
        this.#tracer = tracer;
        if (tracer) {
            this.#trace = (msg) => {
                tracer.push(msg);
            };
        } else {
            this.#trace = undefined;
        }
    }

    doSomething() {
        const sideEffect = () => {
            console.log("interpolated!");
            return 42;
        };
        this.#trace?.(`${sideEffect()}`);
    }
}

const ex = new Example();

console.log("doSomething without tracing:");
ex.doSomething();

ex.setTracer([]);
console.log("doSomething with tracing:");
ex.doSomething();
```

Comment: I'd prefer to do something not bespoke, (hence I also included that as suggestions I am willing to take).  This is my first javascript/typescript project so a bit new to me.  But the above suggestion I like, it remove any real performance hit when tracing is not enabled..